# Contouring building faces in Sketchup

Tags: sketchup

This may not be possible, but what I'm looking to do is represent data points on a buildings facade in Sketchup.  A good example would be a way to show wind pressure at certain points on the building face.  This could be represented with points on the surface or with contours. Does anyone know of a way to do this using either plugins or the Ruby Console?

To clarify, I would like to be able to visualize text based data on a building facade.  I have xyz (UTM) data with a fourth column which represents a concentration, pressure, etc. I have not imported the data into Sketchup in any way, and am looking for a way to display this data in sketchup.

Thanks

Comment: Is the question how to calculate  wind pressure, or how to display text data at given points in the model?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, edited to reflect that I wan't to display the results.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear the details around this. Have you calculated this in Ruby itself? Or some other application?
What code do you already have?
When you say points on the surface - how does that illustrates wind pressure? Point density? Or did you mean arrows?
It's certainly possible to illustrate with either geometry or making a Ruby Tool that draws stuff in the viewport.

Comment: added more clarifications.  Thanks.  Don't worry about the type of data, as this isn't a solution for one variable only.  I simply want a way to display text based modelling data (xyzV) data in Sketchup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Entities.add_text` to add text labels to points in the model:
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/entities.php#add_text

```
model = Sketchup.active_model
entities = model.active_entities
leader_vector = Geom::Vector.new(5, 5, 5)
entities.grep(Sketchup::Face) { |face|
  face.vertices.each { |vertex|
    point = vertex.position
    entities.add_text('Some text data', point, leader_vector)
  }
}
```

I hope this get you started.